# When i return value to my view pages then there should be an error . $student is defined variable . I Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

here is the function is given below

```
public function index(){
    $student=Administration::Where('payment',1)->get();
    //dd($student);
    return view('HallAuthority.index',compact('student'));
}
```

Here is the view blade

```
    <div class="container-fluid page-body-wrapper">
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
    <!-- partial:partials/_sidebar.html -->
    @include('HallAuthority.inc.sidebar')
    <!-- partial -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid-margin">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
               {{$student->count()}}
              <h2 class="card-title">Total sutdent Student</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="dashboard-chart-card-container">
              <div id="dashboard-card-chart-1" class="card-float-chart"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid-margin">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title">Total Department</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="dashboard-chart-card-container">
              <div id="dashboard-card-chart-2" class="card-float-chart"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid-margin">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title">stock price Price</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="dashboard-chart-card-container">
              <div id="dashboard-card-chart-3" class="card-float-chart"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 grid-margin">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title">Revenue</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="dashboard-chart-card-container">
              <div id="dashboard-card-chart-4" class="card-float-chart"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- content-wrapper ends -->
    <!-- partial:partials/_footer.html -->
    <div class="card card-body">
      <div class="card-header text-center">
        <a href="">Mahfujur@2019</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- partial -->
  </div>
  <!-- row-offcanvas ends -->
</div>
```

**The Route file is given below**

```
Route::get('/student/hall','HallController@index')->name('student.hall');
```

Given this type an error

> Undefined variable: student (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectFinall\resources\views\HallAuthority\index.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectFinall\resources\views\HallAuthority\index.blade.php)*

I get the value properly but i cannot compact this value to the view pages its always shows that it is undefined value i am totally fed up to solve this . Please anyone help me.

Comment: Whats does var_dump($student) show ?

Comment: yes its show .but i can't return this value to view page

Comment: Did you try `return view('HallAuthority.index')->with('student',compact('student'));`

Comment: Its show same type of error

Comment: Sir can you help me via TeamViewer . Please Sir If you have time please help me .

Comment: @MahfujurRahman I can do,

Comment: @IsThisJavascript if they did that then `$student` would be an array with a key named 'student' that contains the object

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function index(){
    $student=Administration::Where('payment',1)->count();
    return view('HallAuthority.index',compact('student'));
}
```

```
<div class="card-body">
               {{$student}}
     <h2 class="card-title">Total sutdent Student</h2>
</div>
```